# Efficient approach in the grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, counting, simulated-annealing

**Problem:** we have to fill a 2D grid of size m*n with characters from the set S such that number of distinct sub-matrices in the resulting grid are close to a given number k.
This question is derived from http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/GERALD09

**Limits:**
1<=n,m<16
1<=k <=m*n*m*n 
|S|=4
time limit=0.1 sec

**Assumption:** Two sub-matrices are distinct if they are not having same dimensions or at least a pair of characters at their corresponding locations doesn't match.

**My approach:** We can start with a random grid and loop while acceptable solution is found and in each iteration, we can increase/decrease randomness depending on our current state(but we can stuck in local optimum states).

But the problem is that I don't know efficient way to calculate number of different sub-matrices in a sub-grid.I tried hashing for counting which is pretty fast ( O(n<sup>2</sup>m<sup>2</sup>)*cost of generating/searching a hash value for a sub-grid).
But this approach doesn't give exact answers due to collisions of hash values and even after correcting it using the comment of @Vaughn Cato I can carry 15-25 iterations for optimum state finding and that is not enough .

Recently, I learned that Simulated annealing can be used to solve these kinds of problems.
http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/simulated-annealing-algorithm-for-beginners/6

I am searching for any efficient approach for solving this optimization problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the hash table to limit the number of possibilities?  That is, you keep a table listing all the sub-matrices that have a particular hash value, then you just check each new entry for duplicates within the same list.

Comment: thanks , but even after that I wouldn't be able find the close to optimal within the time limit .Actually, I was looking for other more efficient approaches.

Comment: how can k be larger than m*n? isn't it like that having smallest matrices with size of single character will result in maximum of m*n distinct matrices?

Comment: @rostok , If we consider all distinct matrices of any dimension ,then we have m*n different options for the top left corner and m*n for diagonally opposite corner of any sub-matrix , thus giving at most m*n*m*n potentially distinct matrices in the worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they will post an editorial at some point, but here is a possible idea for this particular problem:

I generated locally all possible numbers of sub matrices possible for particular `n` and `m`.
For `n=m=3` I got only `11` out of `81` possibilities.
For `n=3,m=4` I got only `19` out of possible `144` values.
What's more, when I generated the values, I obtained all `19` possible options  at the very beginning - after `263000` matrices out of possible `16M` I already had them. (I generated in the lexicographical order)

So, I assume, one possible solution might be to precompute as many as possible different values of `K` that can be achieved for given `n` and `m`, save either the seed for random generator or in some other way such that you need `O(1)` characters per `n-m-k` triplet, and for a particular test case just check two neighboring values - first `k` larger and smaller than given.

What's more, since number of possible `K` values is not large, it may be possible to generate them in other way: given all possible values of `K` for `nxm` table, along with the appropriate tables, we can only backtrack through the values in the next row, and try to obtain all possible matrices with all different values of `K` for `nx(m+1)`.